# Need help with custom rewrite rule

Tags: url-rewriting, query, rewrite-rules

I have a CPT called `presskit`, and I need to add a custom query var named `welcome_box`. I have this code right now:

```
function my_new_url_querystring(){
    add_rewrite_tag( '%welcome_box%','([^&]+)' );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'presskit/(.?.+?)/box/(.+)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=presskit&pagename=$matches[1]&welcome_box=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );

}
add_action( 'init', 'my_new_url_querystring' );
```

When I try to open `mysite.com/presskit/presskit-name/box/john-doe`, it gets back to `mysite.com/presskit/presskit-name/`.

If I open `mysite.com/presskit/presskit-name/?welcome_box=john-doe`, It works and I can get the query var.

What am I doing wrong? I'm not good with regexes, so maybe the erros is there.

Any tips are welcome!

### Update

Thanks to the @Milo answer, I could make it work. Here's the working code:

```
function my_new_url_querystring(){
    add_rewrite_tag( '%welcome_box%','([^&]+)' );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'presskit/([^/]+)/message-to/(.*)?/?$',
        'index.php?presskit=$matches[1]&welcome_box=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );

}
add_action( 'init', 'my_new_url_querystring' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pagename` is for the page post type, if you are trying to pass the slug for the `presskit` post type, remove `post_type` and `pagename` and just set `presskit=$matches[1]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Milo! What I'm trying to do is get the `presskit` post as usual, but add the string `box/john-doe` at the end, allowing this way to get the query var `box` as `john-doe`. I updated the rules with our tip, but it doesn't work yet, it redirects to a page with the `Hello World` post.

Comment: did you flush rewrite rules? it's probably easier for your purposes to just use [`add_rewrite_endpoint`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint), it generates the correct rules for you.

Comment: This is a great tip! `add_rewrite_endpoint` works, but adds it to all post types, while I just want to add for my `presskit` CPT.

Turns out that you were right, and I had a typo with my rewrite rules. I'll update the code with the right rewrite rule. Thanks!